# Finding linear independence in $v_1,\ldots,v_m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

First, I'll try not to ramble, although it tends to happen when I type.

I have the following linear algebra problem for my homework.

Prove or give a counterexample: If $v_1, v_2, \ldots , v_m$ are linearly independent vectors in $V$, then $5v_1 − 4v_2, v_2, \ldots , v_m$ is linearly independent.

My first thought was: "It's obviously not linearly independent. $5v_1 - 4v_2$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$."

But then I noticed that $v_1$ wasn't actually in that set, so then I got to thinking that because we're getting a new vector from one vector that's already in the set, and one vector that's outside the set, but that *would* be independent of the rest if it *was* in it, then that resulting vector ($5v_1 - 4v_2$) is also independent.

Which one is correct? My gut is telling me that the second one is correct. But I can't think of a way to really prove that $5v_1 - 4v_2$ definitely can't be made by a linear combination of any other vectors in that set.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your reasoning is sound, but that's not quite a proof. You usually prove things are linearly independent by making a linear combination and setting it equal to zero, so give that a try. In this case, it should be rather direct once you set up the form. If you like, I can be more specific in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases $\def\v{{\bf v}}5\v_1-4\v_2$ might be expressible in terms of $\v_2,\ldots,\v_m$.  But the important thing to realise is that in this problem it is given that $\v_1,\ldots,\v_m$ are independent - that makes all the difference.

To see whether $5\v_1-4\v_2,\v_2,\ldots,\v_m$ are independent, make a linear combination equal to the zero vector:
$$\lambda_1(5\v_1-4\v_2)+\lambda_2\v_2+\cdots+\lambda_m\v_m={\bf0}\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Rearranging terms,
$$(5\lambda_1)\v_1+(\lambda_2-4\lambda_1)\v_2+\lambda_3\v_3+\cdots+\lambda_m\v_m={\bf0}\ .$$
$\color{red}{\hbox{Since $\v_1,\ldots,\v_m$ are independent}}$ (the key fact), all the coefficients on the LHS must be zero:
$$5\lambda_1=0\ ,\quad \lambda_2-4\lambda_1=0\ ,\quad \lambda_3=0\ ,\ldots,\quad \lambda_m=0\ .$$
You can easily see from this that
$$\lambda_1=0\ ,\quad \lambda_2=0\ ,\quad \lambda_3=0\ ,\ldots,\quad \lambda_m=0\ .$$
So the only way $(*)$ can hold is when all the scalar coefficients are zero; so the vectors are linearly independent.